# Wie nennt man Fragen wie »Kennt sich wer mit XYZ aus?«?

Tags: terminology, question

Ich meine mal gelesen zu haben, dass es für Fragen nach dem Schema

> Kennt sich wer mit XYZ aus?
>   Weißt du etwas zum Thema XYZ?

eine besondere Bezeichnung gibt.  Wie lautet die Bezeichnung für Fragen, die nicht direkt eine Frage sind, sondern der oben genannten Form entsprechen?

Comment: Meinst Du "[Entscheidungsfrage](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Entscheidungsfrage)", oder suchst Du nach einer Bezeichnung für Fragen, die wie eine Entscheidungsfrage formuliert, aber eigentlich als [Ergänzungsfrage](http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erg%C3%A4nzungsfrage) gemeint sind? Oder etwas anderes?

Comment: In wie fern ist das denn keinen normale Frage?

Comment: Falsch: »Kennt sich *wer* mit ... aus?« Richtig: »Kennt sich **jemand** mit ... aus?«

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Meinst Du in einem bestimmten Zusammenhang oder ganz allgemein?

Im Bereich Computer/Internet/Foren/Chats sind solche Fragen als *Metafragen* bekannt (und nicht besonders beliebt), siehe z. B. http://metafrage.de/ oder http://channel.debian.de/netiquette/ch-rules.html